# Noob versus delete?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871942/algorithm-using-pseudocode-for-fetching-records-from-database

I'm pretty nearly certain that this OP asked this question, and it got deleted in relatively short order. So, here he is again, and this was his response to my comment pointing out that he had previously already asked this question:

> I have no idea about that. I logged in today and didn't find my post - so I re-posted it

Given that he can't see deleted posts, how is he supposed to get the message that his question was a dud if it has disappeared without a trace from his point of view?

Or am I missing some interaction point?

Comment: If you leave a comment they should see it in their inbox, which still links them to the deleted post, but usualy I wait a while to delete (or let auto-delete do it) if it's not something like spam that's obviously not okay and needs to go now

Comment: @Ben Brocka: He's not a mod, so the OP won't see it.

Comment: This is what I found (10k viewing only): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864670/algorithms-for-database-queries-in-shortest-time

Comment: What we actually need is a delayed deletion feature, instead of instant. When it pertains to low quality noise, there isn't as much urge as as with spam or illegal postings. But the community votes need to take place before it flows out of the attention window. So voting with a default 48h grace period for deletion should be the default.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn that was it. I have little hope for this OP, but  what little there is would come from reading what's in there.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn you can still see your own deleted question if you're linked to it

Comment: @Ben: only if you have at least 10K reputation points.

Comment: It's something of an ["enforced default"](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) already, @mario - but users with at least 20K reputation points [are exempt from it](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user).